# OPENXML Remote Scan Performance

Tags: sql, t-sql, openxml

I'm looking for some advice on OPENXML.  Specifically, the performance.  I am seeing very slow performance on a very small piece of XML.

Something about this is causing a Remote Scan.  Any ideas on how to go about tuning it?

```
    DECLARE @idoc int
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @ResourceXML

    DECLARE @tmpRes TABLE (ResourceID int, Quantity int, FormID int)

    INSERT INTO @tmpRes (ResourceID, Quantity, FormID)
    SELECT  TMP.ID, TMP.Q, RESC.FormID 
    FROM    OPENXML(@idoc, '/Resources/R') WITH (ID int, Q int) TMP 
    INNER JOIN dbo.tblResources RESC ON TMP.ID = RESC.ResourceID
    WHERE   RESC.OrgID = @OrgID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remote Scan is what the optimizer uses to access the XML data as OPENXML is actually external to the database engine - so that bit is normal.

However there does seem to be an issue with the statistics that the optimizer uses, this article [here](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2005/xml-execution-plans) discusses that, offers some pointers, but I don't know whether this helps your particular situation.

Comment: The link to the article is dead :(

Comment: Link fixed! Hopefully :)